# How to get a reference to MatStepHeader

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material-stepper

I am using a material stepper control to implement a multi-step workflow. There are times when I need to set focus to the current step header. The `MatStepHeader` directive exposes a `focus` method, but I can't find any way to get a reference to the step header directives.

Things I have tried so far:

- `ViewChildren(MatStepHeader)` - this doesn't return anything.
- Add explicit `<mat-step-header></mat-step-header>` markup to the steps - this does not render correctly.

None of the other stepper-related components (e.g., `MatStepper` or `MatStep`) expose the header. It seems very strange that `MatStepHeader` would expose an API if it is not accessible.

Is there any way to get references to the header directives in a stepper?